# How to replace all non-numeric entries with NaN in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have various csv files and I import them as a DataFrame. The problem is that many files use different symbols for missing values. Some use nan, others NaN, ND, None, missing etc. or just live the entry empty. Is there a way to replace all these values with a np.nan? In other words, any non-numeric value in the dataframe becomes np.nan. Thank you for the help.

Comment: `read_csv` accepts a `na_value` arg, you can pass a list of the possible na values, otherwise you can call `to_numeric(errors='coerce')` on the df

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns for a post-processing option

Comment: Thanks EdChym, this is helpful.

Comment: Basically if you know all the possible nan values then use `read_csv` if they're unknown but you know that some are invalid then use the post-processing option

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found what I think is a relatively elegant but also robust method:

```
def isnumber(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

df[df.applymap(isnumber)]
```

In case it's not clear: You define a function that returns `True` only if whatever input you have can be converted to a float. You then filter `df` with that boolean dataframe, which automatically assigns `NaN` to the cells you didn't filter for.

Another solution I tried was to define `isnumber` as

```
import number
def isnumber(x):
    return isinstance(x, number.Number)
```

but what I liked less about that approach is that you can accidentally have a number as a string, so you would mistakenly filter those out. This is also a sneaky error, seeing that the dataframe displays the string `"99"` the same as the number `99`.

**EDIT:**

In your case you probably still need to `df = df.applymap(float)` after filtering, for the reason that `float` works on all different capitalizations of `'nan'`, but until you explicitely convert them they will still be considered strings in the dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

## Replacing non-numeric entries on read, the easier (more safe) way

### TL;DR: Set a datatype for the column(s) that aren't casting properly, and supply a list of na_values

```py
# Create a custom list of values I want to cast to NaN, and explicitly 
#   define the data types of columns:
na_values = ['None', '(S)', 'S']
last_names = pd.read_csv('names_2010_census.csv', dtype={'pctapi': np.float64}, na_values=na_values)
```

### Longer Explanation

I believe best practices when working with messy data is to:

- Provide datatypes to pandas for columns whose datatypes are not inferred properly.
- Explicitly define a list of values that should be cast to NaN.

This is quite easy to do.

Pandas `read_csv` has a list of values that it looks for and automatically casts to NaN when parsing the data (see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) of `read_csv` for the list). You can extend this list using the na_values parameter, and you can tell pandas how to cast particular columns using the dtypes parameter.

In the example above, `pctapi` is the name of a column that was casting to object type instead of float64, due to NaN values. So, I force pandas to cast to float64 and provide the read_csv function with a list of values to cast to `NaN`.

### Process I follow

Since data science is often completely about process, I thought I describe the steps I use to create an na_values list and debug this issue with a dataset.

#### Step 1: Try to import the data and let pandas infer data types. Check if the data types are as expected. If they are = move on.

[image]

In the example above, Pandas was right on about half the columns. However, I expected all columns listed below the 'count' field to be of type float64. We'll need to fix this.

#### Step 2: If data types are not as expected, explicitly set the data types on read using dtypes parameter. This will throw errors by default on values that cannot be cast.

```py
# note: the dtypes dictionary specifying types. pandas will attempt to infer
#   the type of any column name that's not listed
last_names = pd.read_csv('names_2010_census.csv', dtype={'pctwhite': np.float64})
```

Here's the error message I receive when running the code above:
[image]

#### Step 3: Create an explicit list of values pandas cannot convert and cast them to NaN on read.

From the error message, I can see that pandas was unable to cast the value of `(S)`. I add this to my list of na_values:

```
# note the new na_values argument provided to read_csv
last_names = pd.read_csv('names_2010_census.csv', dtype={'pctwhite': np.float64}, na_values=['(S)'])
```

Finally, I repeat steps 2 & 3 until I have a comprehensive list of dtype mappings and na_values.

If you're working on a hobbyist project this method may be more than you need, you may want to use u/instant's answer instead. However, if you're working in production systems or on a team, it's well worth the 10 minutes it takes to correctly cast your columns.

Comment: What do you do if the values you want to convert to NaN don't have a single value or a few values, but instead have a similar form? For instance, if I want a column to be numeric, but some of its entries are different strings, how do I remove them?