# How to set unexpected data type to na?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3,'str']})

    foo
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   str
```

I want to set the data type to int64:

```
a['foo'].astype('int32')
```

but I got an error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'str'
```

How to set unexpected data type to NA. In my case, I'd like to return data frame like the following:

```
    foo
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   NA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all non-numeric entries with NaN in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938549/how-to-replace-all-non-numeric-entries-with-nan-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: You cannot have `dtype 'int32'` and `NA` values at the same time in a `Series`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best is convert all values to `float`s, because `NaN`s are `float` by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
df = pd.to_numeric(df['foo'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    NaN
Name: foo, dtype: float64
```

But if really need integers with floats, is possible this hack:

```
df = df['foo'].where(df['foo'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int)))
print (df)
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

---

```
print (df.apply(type))
0      <class 'int'>
1      <class 'int'>
2      <class 'int'>
3    <class 'float'>
Name: foo, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using `isalpha`

```
a.foo.mask(a.foo.str.isalpha().notnull())
Out[331]: 
0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
Name: foo, dtype: object
```